# Merge columns and State abbreviation to full state name

Tags: string, vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and have been trying everything I can do to accomplish this task. But no luck.

My goal is combining   Column H (State) & Column G (City) & with '-' for domestic address. While replacing all the U.S states abbreviations in full name.

Also, for international address, combining Column J (Country) + '-' + Column G (City)

```
Sub Move_City()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Rows("1:26").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Row As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim StateNm("J") As String

    Select Case TCASE("J")
    Case "CA": StateNm = "California"
    Case "NY": StateNm = "Newyork"

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rng In Cells(Column.Count, "J")

    If Columns("J").Cells = "United States" Then
    sh.Range("W").Value = "J" & " - " & "StateNm"

    ElseIf Columns("J").Cells <> "United States" Then
    sh.Range("W").Value = "J" & " - " & "G"


End Sub
```

When I execute the code, It's giving me a compile error: Type mismatch, by highlighting `StateNm("J") As String`. Can anyone give me any advice on this error?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much, in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Dim StateNm("J") As String` Please explain your thought process here.  It is wrong, but to help we need to know what you meant for it to do.

Comment: @ScottCraner I wanted to declare StateNm variable and put the J in the parenthesis because the column is where state abbreviation is located. Please feel free to follow-up! I will be responsive!

Comment: No End if, No Next, No End Select... Why clearing the Rows, Where do you read column H, G, J...

Comment: I started to fix the code, but there are many issues, and unfortunantly I do not have the time currently to go over everything.  But a few items; You will need to loop through column J and test each one, trying to do it in bulk that way is not correct.  the `()` means array and you can't have a string as the size of the array.  You are missing `End If` and `Next` throughout.  do some research on If Statements and for loops.  At this point it would be complete rewrite and like I said I do not have the time.  One more you cannot equate a multi cell range to one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for updating column W with `State - City` for domestic and `Country - City` for international, you may try something like this:

```
Sub Move_City()
    Dim i As Integer
    Range("W2", Range("W2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(10)) 'assuming 1st row is for heading and there's no blank row in between 1st & last non-blank row
        If Range("J" & i) = "United States" Then Range("W" & i) = StateNm(Range("H" & i)) & " - " & Range("G" & i)
        If Range("J" & i) <> "United States" Then Range("W" & i) = Range("J" & i) & " - " & Range("G" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
Function StateNm(s As String) As String
    Select Case s
        Case "CA": StateNm = "California"
        Case "NY": StateNm = "Newyork"
    End Select
End Function
```